# Use COUNT_DISTINCT(field) on REST SOQL API query

Tags: soql, rest-api

I'm currently trying to run the following SOQL query using the REST API:

```
SELECT Id, accountId, COUNT_DISTINCT(accountId) 
FROM Contact 
WHERE Phone LIKE '%" + CLI + "' 
  OR HomePhone LIKE '%" + CLI + "' 
  OR MobilePhone LIKE '%" + CLI + "'"
```

However I get 400 bad request returned every time. If I take `COUNT_DISTINCT` out I get the following result:

```
{
  "totalSize": 2,
  "done": true,
  "records": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "Contact",
        "url": "/services/data/v27.0/sobjects/Contact/003M000000LJ2233P"
      },
      "Id": "003M000000LJ2233P",
      "AccountId": "001M000000Op99999",
      "Account": {
        "attributes": {
          "type": "Account",
          "url": "/services/data/v27.0/sobjects/Account/001M000000Op99999"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "Contact",
        "url": "/services/data/v27.0/sobjects/Contact/001M000000O123456F"
      },
      "Id": "001M000000O123456F",
      "AccountId": "001M000000OpMj5555",
      "Account": {
        "attributes": {
          "type": "Account",
          "url": "/services/data/v27.0/sobjects/Account/001M000000OpMj5555"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The end goal is to get a count of the number of the accounts for all contacts returned (i.e 15 contacts found from 3 different accounts).

Is that possible using `COUNT_DISTINCT` or will I have to use C# to process the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're missing your GROUP BY in the SOQL query. Try debugging it in [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/).

Your SOQL should be

```
SELECT Id, COUNT_DISTINCT(accountId) FROM Contact WHERE Phone LIKE '%" + CLI + "' OR HomePhone LIKE '%" + CLI + "' OR MobilePhone LIKE '%" + CLI + "'" GROUP BY Id
```

Comment: Using that exact query I get a '400 Bad Response' back. Could it be potentially something underlying with the CLIs or is there something in the query that could cause it?

Comment: What is CLI? Also, you'll either need to build up the SOQL as a string or use variable binding (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm).

Comment: What are you actually sending on the wire? Are you URL encoding the SOQL query? I just tried `$ curl -L -H 'X-PrettyPrint: 1' -H 'Authorization: Bearer 00D...' 'https://devorg-com-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v27.0/query?q=SELECT%20Id%2C%20COUNT_DISTINCT(accountId)%20FROM%20Contact%20WHERE%20Phone%20LIKE%20%27%25123%27%20OR%20HomePhone%20LIKE%20%27%25123%27%20OR%20MobilePhone%20LIKE%20%27%25123%27%20GROUP%20BY%20Id'` and it worked just fine.